# Normalize Mobile Numbers using Python

Tags: python, django

I have a string of digits, how can I format this as a mobile number?
I am trying to create a python def that takes a string and normalizes them into a format I can use.

I am trying to remove all symbols, spaces and if input digit start with 0 and just leave the numbers. As well as add +98 to the beginning

```
Some trivial examples:

916 222 3344       > +989162223344
09375554433        > +989375554433
+98 912 999 88 77  > +989129998877
```

Comment: Use a library like https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers .

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace like below:

```
str = (str.replace(" ",""))
str = '+98'+str[-10:]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the regular expression in this case , you can eliminate everything except numbers from the input.

here below is the demonstration with the input you provided.

```
import re

inputNumnerList = ['+98 912 999 88 77 ','09375554433       ','916 222 3344       ']

for data in inputNumnerList:
    if data.startswith('+98'):
       data =  data[3:]
    elif data.startswith('0'):
       data =  data[1:] 
    data=re.sub('[^0-9]+','',data)
    data = '+98{}'.format(data)
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
+989129998877
+989375554433
+989162223344
```

Comment: Missed it , Fixed it now